# How to read input from command line?

Tags: shell, unix, input, awk

I have to read certain things from the command line to a shell script which calls an awk script. As far as I know, reading into an awk script is not possible, so I would have to read it into the shell script which then would pass the value of the variable to the awk script so that I could work with it. How can it be done?

Comment: Please give an example of what you have tried so far.  Do you want to prompt for input during the execution of the script or parse options/arguments?

Comment: I can store the user input using getline in the awk BEGIN pattern, but I can't use it in other patterns later. I'm storing a "word" input which I would like to pass to another pattern to find all lines containing this word. 
Something like this: BEGIN{ printf "What's the word: "; getline word < "-";} /(^| )word( |$)/. However, second pattern is not working, because "word" is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

For example in Bash you use `read` to read input into a variable and pass the variable to awk with awk's command line parameter:

```
$ read -p PROMPT var ; awk -v awkvar="$var" 'BEGIN{print "You wrote: " awkvar}'
PROMPTfoo
You wrote: foo
```

Comment: You could prompt user inside awk using printf.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:-

create a shell script with below information

```
vi my.sh
```

Now add below line of script

```
#!/bin/bash

#add your awk command here with $1
echo $1
while shift
do
   #add your awk command here with $i
   echo $1
done
```

Save the file and

```
chmod 777 my.sh
```

Now run:-

```
./my.sh  hello world how are you doing
```

Out put:-

```
hello
world
how
are
you
doing
```